# Взаимодействие компонентов (изменение цвета меток рядом с компонентами), работа с object

Tags: c#, winforms, .net

Здравствуйте.

С c#, и особенно winforms, знаком на достаточно поверхностном уровне, поэтому хочу спросить вашего совета и разъяснений.

Есть форма, на которой отображаются различные данные об объекте. При этом используются разные типы компонентов: `TextBox`, `DateTimePicker` и `RadioButton`. Рядом с каждым компонентом есть Label, в котором отображается название поля. Просто как пример: `Имя`, `Фамилия`, `Дата рождения`, `Пол` и др. При открытии формы данные берутся с какого-то источника и цель в том, чтобы поля, которые не заполнены в базе, подсвечивались другим цветом (не сами поля, а метки рядом с ними), а при изменении данных, выделение цветом убиралось.

Сейчас я это реализовал через поле `Tag` в компонентах - в нём я указываю название компонента `Label`, в котором нужно изменять цвет. Далее, в событиях изменения данных (нажатие мышью на `RadioButton`, нажатие клавиши в `TextBox` и т.д.), вызываются функции:

```
private void RecordChanged(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    ChangeColor(ref sender);
}

private void DataChanged(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ChangeColor(ref sender);
}

private void DataChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChangeColor(ref sender);
}
```

Здесь первый вопрос: можно ли избавиться от такого зоопарка функций, используя только одну?

Дальше по поводу самой функции `ChangeColor`. В неё передаётся объект sender, из которого я получаю название типа компонента и вытаскиваю из компонента значение Tag:

```
var t = sender.GetType();
string tag = "";

dynamic q;
switch (t.Name)
{
    case "RadioButton":
        q = (RadioButton) sender;
        tag = q.Tag.ToString();
        break;
    case "TextBox":
        q = (TextBox) sender;
        tag = q.Tag.ToString();
        break;
    case "DateTimePicker":
        q = (DateTimePicker) sender;
        tag = q.Tag.ToString();
        break;
}
```

Здесь второй вопрос: можно ли реализовать это более красиво? Можно ли вытянуть данные с объекта без его распаковки?

Следом идёт перебор всех компонентов на форме:

```
// Перебор всех компонентов на форме
for (var i = 0; i < Controls.Count; ++i)
{
    if (Controls[i].GetType() == typeof (Label))
    {
        var n = Controls[i].Name;
        if (n == tag)
            Controls[i].ForeColor = changed;
    }
    // перебор всех компонентов в GroupBox'ах
    else if (Controls[i].GetType() == typeof (GroupBox))
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < (Controls[i]).Controls.Count; ++j)
        {
            if ((Controls[i]).Controls[j].GetType() == typeof (Label))
            {
                if ((Controls[i]).Controls[j].Name == tag)
                    (Controls[i]).Controls[j].ForeColor = changed;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Когда пытался сделать перебор через `foreach (var comp in Controls)`, в нём comp является объектом. Опять же, возвращаясь к уже заданному вопросу - как распаковать этот объект (или как вытягивать из него данные, не распаковывая)?

И ещё один вопрос: можно ли как-то более красиво находить нужные компоненты на форме? Может быть, LINQ или ещё как-нибудь?

А может быть, есть какие-то совсем другие способы решения данной задачи, более простые?

Спасибо за внимание.

.NET Framework 4, VS2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно идти путем, который Вы описываете, но каждый новый элемент формы будет требовать от Вас все больше и больше кода. Постоянный перебор в цикле элементов - верный путь к тормозам интерфейса.

Присмотритесь к своему приложению. Точнее, как его видит пользователь. Он не видит метки и поля ввода. Для него это один комплексный элемент. Поэтому так и нужно сделать - создайте себе новые компоненты - поле вводе с текстом, календарь с текстом. Много однотипного кода уйдет внутрь. Будет легче размещать на форме. Будет легче менять цвет (потому что теперь у нового компонента будет одно свойство), с другой стороны, компонент и сам может поменять свое свойство, если его текст не соответствует нужному.

Почитайте на сайте [майкрософта статью](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/a6h7e207(v=vs.110).aspx), а также [подборку](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w29y3h59(v=vs.110).aspx).

**Обновление**

По поводу своих компонентов (контролов) - это те же библиотечные функции. Если нужна одна штука - пишем по месту. Нужно две - аккуратно копируем и отлаживаем. Как только понадобится третья копия - вот тут начинаем рефакторинг и выделяем одинаковые куски.

То, что Вы называете распаковкой, - плохая затея. Но если выделите код в отдельные контролы, то думаю, что много подобного просто не нужно будет.

**Обновление**

Это называется не распаковка, а приведение типов.

Возьмем, к примеру, большой switch, где Вы пытаетесь взять значение поля tag. Вот как раз для таких целей и создана вся эта иерархия. Смотрим в справку и понимаем, что свойство tag - это свойство   System.Windows.Forms.Control. И весь второй кусок кода сворачивается в

```
string tag = (Control)sender.Tag.ToString();
```

**Обновление**

Распаковка - это unboxing. Да, она похожа на приведение типов, но это немного другое.

Простые типы (такие как int) могут храниться нормально (в виде 4 байт для int), так и в извращенном виде - в виде объекта. Понятно, что иногда их нужно преобразовывать с одного вида в другой (из-за особенностей реализации .NET платформы, которые она честно скопировала с Java).

Так вот. Процесс перевода с нормального вида в объект называется упаковка. Обратный - распаковка.

А привидение объектов распаковкой/упаковкой не являются.

Comment: Спасибо, Вадим, обязательно прочитаю и статью и подборку. Хотя такая форма планируется только одна, думаю, будет разумно сделать свои компоненты. А по поводу извлечения данных/распаковки object не подскажете?

Comment: Да здесь дело не в том, что я буду/не буду использовать распаковку в данном коде, или нет, а в том, что хочу принципиально разобраться, как работать с типом object, если заранее не известен его тип - это может понадобиться в другой ситуации, в другое время и в другом коде.

Comment: Это называется не распаковка, а приведение типов.

Возьмем к примеру большой switch, где Вы пытаетесь взять значение поля tag. Вот как раз для таких целей и создана вся эта иерархия. Смотрим в справку и понимаем, что свойство tag - это свойство   System.Windows.Forms.Control. И весь второй кусок кода сворачивается в

    string tag = (Control)sender.Tag.ToString();

Comment: Как понимаю, приведение объекта к типу как раз и называется распаковкой объекта. Например, цитата из MSDN:

> Распаковка является явным преобразованием из типа object в тип значения или из типа интерфейса в тип значения, реализующего этот интерфейс.

и приведённый там же код:

    int i = 123;      // a value type
    object o = i;     // boxing
    int j = (int)o;   // unboxing

С `Tag` понятно, только нужны дополнительные скобки `string tag = ((Control)sender).Tag.ToString();`, иначе ошибку выдаёт, что вполне логично.

Спасибо, теперь стало понятно!

Comment: распаковка - это unboxing. Да, она похожа на приведение типов, но это немного другое.

Простые типы (такие как int) могут храниться нормально (в виде 4 байт для int), так и в извращенном виде - в виде объекта. Понятно, что иногда их нужно преобразовывать с одного вида в другой (из за особенностей реализации .NET платформы, которые она честно скопировала с Java).

Так вот. Процесс перевода с нормального вида в объект называется упаковка. Обратный - распаковка.

А привидение объектов распаковкой/упаковкой не являются.

Comment: Реализовал свои компоненты - получилось просто, быстро и весьма удобно. Ещё раз спасибо!